# Bulma responsive column collapsing too soon

Tags: html, css, responsive, bulma

```css
.black {
   background-color: black;
   min-width: 318px;
   max-width: 318px;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow column">
   <div class="columns is-multiline is-mobile pt-6">
      <div class="black column mt-4 ml-2 mr-4">
         d
      </div>
      <div class="black column mt-4 ml-2 mr-4">
         d
      </div>
      <div class="black column mt-4 ml-2 mr-4">
         d
      </div>
      <div class="black column mt-4 ml-2 mr-4">
         d
      </div>
      <div class="black column mt-4 ml-2 mr-4">
         d
      </div>
      <div class="black column mt-4 ml-2 mr-4">
         d
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make it where the columns collapse to multi lines when the column reaches the end of the container, like how in fiverr it collapses onto the next line right before it goes out of view, but currently mine goes onto the next line before the zoom reaches the edge of the column [image]

[image]

The product cards how fiverr has it is what I'm trying to [achieve](https://www.fiverr.com/search/gigs?query=draw&source=top-bar&search_in=everywhere&search-autocomplete-original-term=draw)